# Symfony Form How to do it cleaner

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to create new order in eshop, now I have it like this, but is it possible to somehow do this data inserting cleaner or automatic?

```
        $order = new Orders();
        $customers = new Customers();
        foreach ($form['cart']->getData() as $product) {
            if ($product['product']->getQuantity() >= $product['quantity']) {
                $cart = new Cart();
                $cart->setUserId($sessionID);
                $cart->setProductId($product['product']);
                $cart->setQuantity($product['quantity']);
                $cart->setPrice($product['product']->getPrice());
                $cart->setBoughtPrice($product['product']->getBoughtPrice());
                $em->persist($cart);
                $em->flush();
            } else {
                $this->addFlash('error', 'Není skladem tolik kusu!');
                return $this->redirectToRoute('web_admin_cash_register');
            }
        }
        $customers->setBillingFullName($form['customer']['billingFullName']->getData());
        $customers->setBillingAddress($form['customer']['billingAddress']->getData());
        $customers->setBillingCity($form['customer']['billingCity']->getData());
        $customers->setBillingCountry($form['customer']['billingCountry']->getData());
        $customers->setBillingPhoneNumber($form['customer']['billingPhoneNumber']->getData());
        $customers->setBillingPostalCode($form['customer']['billingPostalCode']->getData());
        $customers->setIco($form['customer']['ico']->getData());
        $customers->setDic($form['customer']['dic']->getData());
        $customers->setEmail($form['customer']['email']->getData());
        $em->persist($order);
        $em->flush();
```

Orders Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderItems", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $cart;
```

OrderItems Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Orders", inversedBy="cart")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $order;
```

NewOrderType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('cart', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => CartType::class,
            'label' => false,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'collection',
            ),
        ])
        ->add('customer', BillingInfoType::class);
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
    ));
}
```

CartType(OrderItems):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('product', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'Web\ShopBundle\Entity\Product',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->where('p.enabled = true')
                    ->orWhere('p.quantity >= 1');
            },
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank(['message' => 'Povinné pole'])
            ],
            'choice_label' => 'productCode'
        ])
        ->add('quantity', IntegerType::class);
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(
        []
    );
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What don't you like?

Comment: Check now. I don't like that I'm not using data_class. But I'm not sure if I can in this point.